# Which is the correct way to check for null in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am supposed to refactor this line of Objective-C code:

```
if (_currentImageFrame && ![_currentImageFrame.isSaveToLibrary boolValue]) {}
```

I think of 2 ways to achieve this, but I am not sure which one is better:

1)

```
if (self.currentImageFrame != nil) &&
   (self.currentImageFrame?.isSaveToLibrary == false)
{
}
```

2)

```
if let frame = self.currentImageFrame {

    if self.currentImageFrame?.isSaveToLibrary == true {
    }
}
```

Please let me know which is more recommended/correct way to achieve it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your #2 option would look better if it actually used the `frame` variable you create. Also, if you're checking for `nil` first, you're justified in using `!` instead of `?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `self.currentImageFrame` is an *optional*, the more compact way of doing what you ask is taking advantage of the way *optional chaining* works:

```
if self.currentImageFrame?.isSaveToLibrary == false
{
    // Code
}
```

If `self.currentImageFrame` is not `nil`, `self.currentImageFrame?.isSaveToLibrary` will return the value of `isSaveToLibrary`.

If `self.currentImageFrame` is `nil`, `self.currentImageFrame?.isSaveToLibrary` will return `nil` immediately, without attempting to execute anything that's after the `?` (no matter how deep the chain goes).

`nil` does not equal `false` (unlike Objective-C, in Swift `nil` only equals `nil` and nothing else), hence `nil == false` evaluates to `false`, so the code behaves as you would expect.

---

Note that your 1) option would work but it's completely redundant, as the first check is not needed at all.

I think that your 2) option has a typo, and you intended to write `false` where you typed `true`. With the typo fixed it would work as well (since you are actually using *optional chaining* once again inside the outer condition), but it's using *optional binding* in a wrong way, since you don't use the the bound constant `frame` inside the outer conditional body. A more correct (although redundant as well) way of using *optional binding* would be.

```
if let frame = self.currentImageFrame
{
    if frame.isSaveToLibrary == false
    {
        // Code
    }
}
```

In this case you don't use *optional chaining* at all. (Although I suspect that the optimized compiled code would be the same in both cases).

---

Finally, I suggest you rename `isSaveToLibrary` as it's grammatically incorrect and its meaning is unclear. I would name it `wasSavedToLibrary` or `shouldSaveToLibrary`, depending on the intended use.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the following:

```
if self.currentImageFrame?.isSaveToLibrary == true {
    // Stuff
}
```

Your var currentImageFrame is ? so you don't have to check if it's nil, in case of nil, it is not going to check the if condition, and if it's not nil it is going to check the if and if the condition is satisfied it will enter. Furthermore you don't need to use parenthesis in Swift :)